# Typescript: Can a ternary operator or conditional statement be used inside of a constructor?

Tags: typescript, constructor, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I am working on improving existing code for a webpage. When users are logged on, I want them to have different dropdown options. I am using Angular and the respective component.ts file is set up similar to this...

```
constructor () {
    this.name = this.login ? 'User' : 'Guest';
    ...
    this.list = [
        {display: this.name, value: 'name'},
        {display: this.address, value: 'address'},
        {display: this.company, value: 'company'}
    ];
}
```

In the above example, login is defined outside of the constructor. The this.name display value is the only one giving me a problem. Can ternary operators be used inside of Typescript constructors? If not, how should I set up my condition for the display value to change. I've tried defining the list outside of the constructor, but the page won't display properly.

Comment: Yes you can have a ternary operator in a constructor but i don't get why you don't try it yourself instead of posting a stackoverflow question ;)

Comment: I did try it myself and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't whether a ternary operator *can* be used inside a constructor. The issue is that `this.login` has only one possible state at the time this component is constructed. That said, if the component gets rendered in the view at the time when the user is not logged it, then that will never change when they finally do login (unless you re-construct your component).

Instead, you could use a setter on `login` so that:

```
private _login = false;

get login(): boolean {
  return this._login;
}

set login(value: boolean) {
  this._login = value;
  this.name = value ? 'User' : 'Guest';
}
```